# Call Magento .phtml file via ajax

Tags: ajax, magento

I have my custom magento plugin. I have the image slider in the product page. I want to call ths particular template(abc.phtml) file via ajax in the product page. Can somebody help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create such code in your controller (which will render AJAX call) action:

```
$html = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('core/template')
            ->setTemplate('your_module/abc.phtml')->toHtml();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($html);
```